# GetAttribute("class") don't give any class names

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the class name of `<div>`s but it's not working well for me.
When the app take the result I want it to show into a textbox.

I wrote this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
    textBox1.Text = "f";
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElementCollection inputName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in inputName)
    {
        textBox1.Text += elem.GetAttribute("class") + " \n";
    }
}
```

But when I press the button the output is:

```
f
```

When I tried to change the program from `GetAttribute("class")` > `GetAttribute("id")` the output was correct.

It'll be a lot of help if you'll help me fix this problem.

[image: image of the program]

Comment: if you mean to do like:webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV");
it not working

Comment: `textBox1.Text += elem.GetAttribute("className");`

Answer (score 0):

I am using selenium with C#. This is what worked for me.

> 

// locate web element

// I am using a IWebElement vs HtmlElementCollection however.

HtmlElementCollection inputName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

// use GetAttribute() method on element variable

string className = inputName.GetAttribute("class").ToString();

// print to console

Console.WriteLine(className);

// My working code when solving this

this.selm.CheckIfElementDisplayed(driver, By.XPath(SmartShipLocators.selectAllCheckboxStatus));

IWebElement checkboxEl = this.selm.FindWebElement(driver, By.XPath(SmartShipLocators.selectAllCheckboxStatus));

string className = checkboxEl.GetAttribute("class").ToString();

Assert.AreEqual("checked", className);